# Differentiate source files(.java) as per Screen size?

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I have two layouts in layout-hdpi & layout-mdpi of same activity.
Now I have one button,in both of layout, on this button click i have to open another activity for hdpi device & another relative layout for mdpi device.

So,
I want to make different folder for source files to support multiple screen size Just like layout-hdpi,layout-mdpi....

Comment: i am sure there is no way you can do this. you need to use a swtch case to identify the density dpi and then code accordingly.

Comment: Why, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You want different folders for xml files or for java files?

Comment: @VarunVishnoi I want different folder for java files for xml files I know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think by different folder you mean different packages

You can make a controller class and determine the screen density programatically in which you can decide to call a density(screen category) specific java class..

```
//Determine density and call the specific class as you want
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int density = metrics.densityDpi;

if (density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH) {
    //call package1 classes for High Density devices
}
else if (density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM) {
    //call package2 classes for Medium Density devices
}
else if (density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW) {
    //call package3 classes for Low Density devices
}
else {
    //call package4 classes for rest
}
```

Comment: how should i implement this to switch different activities.

Comment: same approach can be applied for activities too..the only thing is your main activity would be one..which will be a launcher activity and controller as well..

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may want to use something indicated by the layout itself to determine which behavior to envoke. Say you have a view with id `R.id.only_in_hdpi` in the layout in the hdpi folder, and that id isn't present in the mdpi folder. Here is how you would solve your problem:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.only_in_hdpi);
if (v != null) {
    // do whatever you need to if it's hdpi
} else {
    // handle the non-hdpi case
}
```

Important to note that xhdpi will fire the hdpi case, as will xxhdpi

Answer (score 0):

That is against MVC module which is by default followed by Android. For defining a controller you should work in single java file only for each activity.